# Cargar imagen Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Estoy pasando un proyecto realizado en `Typescript` a angular (es un ajedrez). El problema que tengo es que no se como puedo cargar las imágenes de las fichas.

Código que tengo para cargar las fichas;

```
colocarFichas(casilla) : void{
let img = document.createElement("img");
let nombre: string;
    if(casilla.id=="0" || casilla.id=="7"){
      img = document.createElement("img");
      img.setAttribute("src","./torreBlanca.png");
      casilla.appendChild(img);
    nombre="torreBlanco";
    }
    if(casilla.id>=8 && casilla.id<=15){
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src","./peonBlanco.png");
        casilla.appendChild(img);
        nombre="peonBlanco";
    }
    if(casilla.id=="1" || casilla.id=="6"){
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src","./caballoBlanco.png");
        casilla.appendChild(img);
        nombre="caballoBlanco";
    }
```

Y así con todas, el elemento `casilla` es generado dinamicamente mediante código `typescript`;

```
  let tablero = document.getElementById("tablero");
  let nCasillas = 8*8;
for(let i = 0; i<nCasillas; i++){

  if(i%8 ==0){
      var fila = document.createElement("div");
      fila.className="fila";
      this.cambioColor=!this.cambioColor;
  }
  let casilla = document.createElement("div");
  //Evento del click
   casilla.onclick= new function(){
      let idCasillaClicada=casilla.id;

  }
  //Fin evento click
  casilla.id =i.toString();
  casilla.className="casilla";
  fila.appendChild(casilla);
  tablero.appendChild(fila);

  if(this.cambioColor){
  casilla.style.background= "#233472";
  this.cambioColor=false;
  }else{
    this.cambioColor=true;
   }

  this.colocarFichas(casilla);
}//Fin del For
}// Fin del metodo pintar tablero.
```

Las imágenes están alojadas en el mismo directorio que el módulo por lo que `./nombre`creo que tendría que funcionar.

Otra cosa que creo que no hago  bien es la asignacion del evento `click`sobre la casilla `casilla.onclick= new function(){`

Este es el resultado actual que me muestra el navegador;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con Angular, lo mejor que puedes hacer es seguir *sus* reglas o todo se vuelve más complejo: puesto que todo se redirecciona a partir de la URL establecida como base (mira la etiqueta HTML [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/base) que seguro que tienes en tu index.html), tienes que pensar en esa URL cuando buscas una imagen, por lo que te recomiendo que muevas todas las imágenes a la carpeta `assets` de tu proyecto y uses algo como:

```
<img class="logo" src="assets/img/mi-imagen.png ">
```

Si las imágenes no las pones ahí, piensa que Angular se compila cuando quieres pasar a producción, creando un único archivo .js con todos los componentes y sus plantillas, con lo que no sé cómo trataría el compilador las imágenes que se encontrasen en las carpetas de esos compomentes.

Por otro lado, tampoco deberías necesitar usar `document.createElement...` en tu componente, las plantillas (las **vistas**) te permiten definir todo el HTML a mostrar de un modo limpio, dejando el código del componente Typescript para definir el **modelo**.